# What is the proper syntax of the following JSON string

Tags: json

I need to extract data from MSACCES database in JSON object...
So I'm not quite sure about the right JSON string syntax.
Which one is correct:

```
{
  "Continent": {
    "Europe": {
      "Countries": 
        {
          "The Netherlands": {
            "Cities": [
              "Rotterdam",
              "Hag",
              "Amsterdam"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "Germany": {
            "Cities": [
              "Bon",
              "Berlin"
            ]
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

or this one:

```
{
  "Continent": {
    "Europe": {
      "Countries": [
        {
          "The Netherlands": {
            "Cities": [
              "Rotterdam",
              "Hag",
              "Amsterdam"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "Germany": {
            "Cities": [
              "Bon",
              "Berlin"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder between {"Countries":[{"The Net...   or   {"Countries":{"The Net..

Comment: All you have to do is use any programming language and try parsing it. If it's invalid, it will error. And indeed one of the two *is* invalid.

Comment: There are actually a ton of json validators/linters websites.

Comment: What language do you use to produce the JSON? Unless it is some obscure functionality of MS Access, chances are that it either supports JSON natively or a library/module for dealing with JSON exists for it. Don't generate JSON by string concatenation. It is not straightforward and there are many corner cases.

Comment: I first create some object (dictionary, array or collection) and then  parse with  JSON Converter library... VBA does not natively support JSON. And it is a bit confused to me as far as I just started to deal with JSON... So I want to clarify  some unknowns @axiac

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. It can be stored or transmitted over the network but in order to use the encoded data, the JSON must be parsed. The result of parsing is a data structure equivalent to the one used to generate the JSON. You are not parsing JSON. You try to generate JSON. If you use [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) then you need to create the data structure (an object that contains the `Continent` property etc) then pass it to `JsonConverter.ConvertToJson()` to produce a JSON out of it.

Comment: The code example in the documentation of [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) is misleading. `Dim Json As Object` is not JSON, it is an object. This is a common confusion between a JSON and an object used to create the JSON (or decoded from the JSON) that many developers make. Change that to `Dim obj as Object` and the things become more clear.

Comment: I hope you did not generate the first example from your question using VBA-JSON. That is not valid JSON and therefore cannot be parsed.

Comment: No I did not generate with VBA JSON, just I wrote as an example  looking for the result I should get at the and. So I needed better understanding what I suppose  to do exactly  and I used that example with countries just to be more clear   @axiac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are having an array of  `Country[]`, I would advice you to rename your `Country` key by `Countries`:

```json
Countries: [{}, {}]
```

Comment: Yes @devpolo I have array of Country, so the second one should be the correct one...

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best way is to keep relations

```
{
  "Continens": {
    "Continent": "Europe",
    "Countries": [
      {
        "Country": "The Netherlands",
        "Cities": [
          "Rotterdam",
          "Hag",
          "Amsterdam"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Country": "Germany",
        "Cities": [
          "Bon",
          "Berlin"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

classes (translate to your language)

```
 public class World
    {
        public Continens Continens { get; set; }
    }
     public class Continens
    {
        public string Continent { get; set; }
        public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public List<string> Cities { get; set; }
    }
```